# A base64 image is not stored properly in cloud storage for firebase (aka firebase storage)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am uploading a base64 image to **cloud storage for firebase** (aka firebase storage), using the firebase web interface.

The code that I am using for uploading (in React Native) is the following:

```
const ref = await firebase.storage().ref(user).child(curTime.toString());
await ref.putString(base64String, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpeg' })
```

However, when I try to view the image it cannot be displayed.

1. The uploaded string is available in my dropbox, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3c6gtfgnf9a5ig/base64-before-uploading-to-firebase-storage?dl=0) (download to view it).
2. The file in firebase cloud storage is available [here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/native-sample-68693.appspot.com/o/test1%40mail_com%2F1543162838114?alt=media&token=8a675c79-37bb-423b-a596-052609c2caea).
3. I have downloaded this file into my dropbox, you can access it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qr48pwnx7ltuuu/file-stored-in-firebase-1543162838114?dl=0) (download to view it).

#### Here is the relevant code:

```
const uploadImageAsync = async(userId, curTime, photoUri) => {
  const user = normalizeUserId(userId); // prepare for firebase write
  let firebaseImageUrl = null;
  let base64String;
  try {
    base64String = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(photoUri,
      { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingTypes.Base64 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }

  const ref = await firebase.storage().ref(user).child(curTime.toString());

  await ref.putString(base64String, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpeg' })
  .then(async(snapshot) => {
    await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(uploadURL => {
      firebaseImageUrl = uploadURL;
    }, (error) => { // failed to get uploadedURL location
      console.log(error);
      return null;
    });
  }, (error) => { // failed to upload image to firebase storage);
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  });

  return firebaseImageUrl;
};
```

Comment: what do you mean with not stored properly?

Comment: You cannot view it in the firebase console.

Comment: should firebase console show the base64 icons? i mean try to download the ref and render it on react-native  in order to see if they are stored and the data is not malformed. If the could be downloaded from firebase and you can see it on react-native means that firebase console dont support base64 img vizualitation

Comment: Images can be displayed on the console, I am sure. I also tried displaying with the app, no luck.

Comment: try with this ..`ref.putString(base64String, 'base64')` also remove the opt contentType part. and let me know if there is some success

Comment: Doesn't help. The file type is now 'application/octet-stream' and it cannot be displayed as an image (by referencing it with its URL).

Comment: could you please share the full code/function? im pretty sure you are not following the firebase example.. y want to help you. do you user react native firebase or firebase for web clients?

Comment: @HelmerBarcos Sorry for the delay. I missed the notification about your last comment. Added the code. Thanks for your help!